# Resolve relative ("~") paths without reference to the current Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a generic library for use by all of my web projects. One of the functions is a permanent redirect as below:

```
public static void PermanentRedirect(string url, HttpResponse response, bool endResponse)
{
    url = //resolve url here. how?

    response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    response.AddHeader("Location", url);

    if (endResponse) response.End();
}
```

How can I resolve the URL without having to pass the current page to get access to `Page.ResolveUrl`? Note, I *can* change the method signature, but I would prefer not to because I think it would overburden the API.

I have a couple overloads for this so my desired usage is:

```
WebUtility.PermanentRedirect("~/somewhere/somepage.aspx")
```

Comment: What *does* `~` mean in that case? (Relative to what? I believe the two-param URI constructor will handle it "as expected".) The Page can be accessed directly from the HttpContext, if it can't be obtained otherwise.

Comment: The `~` would be the normal web application root operator that maps to the web application root. Regarding the Uri constructor, are you referring to `new Uri(string uriString, bool dontEscape)`? That is depreciated and I'm not sure if the other will apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath) as a direct replacement for tilde.

You can also use [VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150163.aspx), but it doesn't like query strings - so you have to parse them out (or, preferably, use UriBuilder).

Oh - and off-topic, but IMHO an extension method off HttpResponse would make syntax a bit easier.

Comment: The extension method is a nice idea. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

[This method should work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160.aspx):

```
url = VirtualPathUtiliy.ToAbsolute(url);
```

Comment: +1 i've only just understood what OP is asking. He just wants to resolve that url.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes. This is what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current page instance via [`HttpContext.Handler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler.aspx):

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (page != null)
{
     // Use page instance, f.e. page.Request.Url;
}
```

By the way, you don't need to pass the `HttpResponse` either:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tim. I should have been more clear. I would like to avoid referencing the page altogether. Do you think I am being unreasonable to enforce that constraint? It just kinda seems fragile to have to do it that way.

Comment: @Jeff: Why do you want the url of the current page without referencing it? Of course it's fragile if it's called in a non-web project. But that's not the case.

Comment: It seems to me that there should be a way to do it without referencing `HttpContext.Current.Handler`. Needing to reference the page would introduce a dependency that would complicate things in non-standard scenarios like unit testing.

Comment: @Jeff So put the HttpContext stuff behind a facade that is injected or otherwise... the issues stands: relative to *what*?

Comment: @Jeff: There is. Nevertheless, you should be putting this functionality into an injected utility anyway. Even relying on the application context (as opposed to the Http context) makes your unit tests depend on outside information which is best controlled using mocks.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry if I was not clear in my requirements or wording.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'm relatively new to dependency injection (is that what you were referring to?) so I will have to read up on that. Are you saying that `VirtualPathUtiliy` has dependencies that would cause it to fail in unit tests?

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, it has to know the context of your application in order to determine what `~/` means. So that path could change from instance to instance. I don't even know if such a thing would *exist* in a unit-test context. Since you want your unit tests to be deterministic, it's better to use a utility object that can either be mocked, faked, or configured to return exactly what you want it to.

Comment: Obviously, in a POCO unit test example - *every* method of resolving the web root will fail. Because there is no web root. Because there is no web. Standard mocking can handle that though. [One of] The real reason[s] you don't want HttpContext.Current.Handler is because of handlers that aren't Pages where you may want to reference a URL- eg., an ASHX.